# SharpSsh Command Execution

Tags: c#, linux, ssh

I am trying to create a SSH client using C#. I am using the Tamir.SharpSsh library. I am having issues sending the command and getting an appropriate response from the server.

The way I have been testing it is by sending over the `ls` command, followed by `cd..` command, followed by `ls` command again -- to see whether or not the `cd..` command is being executed properly. However, there is no difference between the first `ls` command and the second `ls` command. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. Perhaps I am using the wrong Ssh type. I have provided the code and the output I am getting. I have also added the output that I expect.

```
using Tamir.SharpSsh;

namespace SSHNetExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SshExec ssh = null;
            try
            {
                Console.Write("-Connecting...");
                ssh = new SshExec(host, username, password);

                ssh.Connect();

                Console.WriteLine("OK ({0}/{1})", ssh.Cipher, ssh.Mac);
                Console.WriteLine("Server version={0}, Client version={1}", ssh.ServerVersion, ssh.ClientVersion);
                Console.WriteLine("-Use the 'exit' command to disconnect.");
                Console.WriteLine();

                while(true)
                {
                    string command = Console.ReadLine();

                    if(command == "exit")
                        break;
                    string data = ssh.RunCommand(command);

                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            if(ssh != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting...");
                ssh.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SshExec class is for executing a single command.  It logs into the server for each command, and executes the command you asked it to.  It's similar (but not the same) as you logging in, typing `cd  ..`, logging out again, logging in again and typing `ls` - when you logged in the second time you were redirected to the home directory.

If you want to continue to use the SshExec, you should combine your commands so you can just execute a single command.  In this instance, for example, you would execute `ls ..`.

If you want to be able to issue multiple commands like an interactive session, look at the `SshShell` class instead of `SshExec`.

Comment: Could you give an example using the SshShell? I have tried to use it before the SshExec, and I was not able to get it to work. I am confused as to what goes into the ExpectPattern attribute and Pattern function.

Comment: No, sorry, I switched away from using SharpSSH because it wasn't being maintained.  I now use the SSH.NET(https://sshnet.codeplex.com/) library instead, which has better documentation and more recent updates.

Comment: Thank you for that Richard. I went ahead and migrated to using SSH.NET. I have not really been able to find too much documentation on it. I did post another question which recreates the problem I was having on this question using SSH.NET

http://stackoverflow.com/q/29397766/2970916