# SshNet Command Execution

Tags: c#, linux, ssh

I am trying to create a SSH client using C#. I am using the Renci.SshNet library. I am having issues sending the command and getting an appropriate response from the server.

The way I have been testing it is by sending over the ls command, followed by cd.. command, followed by ls command again -- to see whether or not the cd.. command is being executed properly. However, there is no difference between the first ls command and the second ls command. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. Perhaps I am using the wrong Ssh type. I have provided the code and the output I am getting. I have also added the output that I expect.

```
        SshClient ssh = new SshClient("apk0rhel01", "dwaseem", "Da_011235813");
        ssh.Connect();


        while (true)
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine();

            if (command == "exit")
            {
                break;
            }

            var result = ssh.RunCommand(command);

            if (result.Result.Length < 10)
                continue;

            Console.Write(result.Result);
        }
        ssh.Disconnect();
```

Output:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is the same as the one for your question using the Tamir SSH library - you are using a class intended for executing single commands, which logs in and executes the command each time.  You will not be able to use this like a shell.

If you want to implement interactive commands, you'll need something which keeps the connection open, and you'll need to deal with working out when a command has finished (which is normally done by looking for the prompt pattern).  The Shell class provides methods for dealing with this - you can find examples of its use [on their website](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/301739).

Comment: Richard, thank you for helping me. I tried to use the Shell class but I am having some issues with it. I posted another question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/29414343/2970916

Comment: The link in the above comment is no longer valid.  It takes you to a page telling that the question was removed.  And,  above that, the link "on their website" takes you to a page that redirects you  to github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

On a personal note, I'm still looking (unsuccessfully so far) for documentation or an example of using the shell class.